# Using Firebase Cloud Functions to fetch data from api?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I have a use case where I want to call an API to fetch data twice without any trigger from the front-end and I'm wondering if firebase cloud functions are of any help in this regard.

Basically what I. want is, to get data from API (twice a day), store it in firestore and firebase storage, and call the firebase API from the front-end.

Please suggest me, if I should even consider firebase cloud functions for the task!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Firebase Scheduled Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that runs twice a day:

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0,12 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every day at 00:00 AM and 12:00 PM Eastern!');
  // Do your stuff
  //admin.firestore().collection("test").doc("test").set({...})
  return null;
});
```

The above function will be triggered twice a day - once at midnight and second at 12 noon. There you can fetch your data from any 3rd party API and write it to firestore. The parameter passed in the schedule method is in cron syntax. You can experiment different cron schedules [here](https://crontab.guru/)

Comment: Sure, actually I'm waiting until we try it :)

Comment: @ASADHAMEED great! btw you can also use this cron `functions.pubsub.schedule('*/5 * * * *')` to run the function every 5 minutes for testing :wink: